# Sonata Admin - Custom AJAX call

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, sonata-admin, symfony-2.3

I have created a custom list view in `sonata admin` to display a calendar.

I'm trying to add events to the calendar dynamically, but I'm getting an error with the `CSRF` token being invalid.

I have the following code:

```
public function listAction()
{
    if (false === $this->admin->isGranted('LIST')) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException();
    }

    $datagrid = $this->admin->getDatagrid();
    $formView = $datagrid->getForm()->createView();

    // set the theme for the current Admin Form
    $this->get('twig')->getExtension('form')->renderer->setTheme($formView, $this->admin->getFilterTheme());

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $events = $em->getRepository('BMCrmBundle:Event')->findAll();

    $event = new Event();

    $formEvent = $this->createForm(new EventType(), $event );

    return $this->render($this->admin->getTemplate('list'), array(
        'action'     => 'list',
        'form'       => $formView,
        'datagrid'   => $datagrid,
        'csrf_token' => $this->getCsrfToken('sonata.batch'),
        'events'     => $events,
        'formEvent'  => $formEvent->createView()
    ));
}
```

view

```
var url = "{{ path('create_event', { _sonata_admin: 'bm.crm.admin.event'} ) }}";
$.post(url, form.serialize(), function(data) {
   alert(data);
});
```

This always returns that the CSRF token is invalid

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if in your view, you have the following line:

```
{{ form_rest(form) }}
```

because I believe that you are rendering form fields one by one and not the whole form at once and forgot to render the rest of the form, which contains the CSRF token.

Comment: I did notice and it seems to have fixed my issue. Thank you

Comment: Is there an easy way to validate form via ajax?