# Symfony2 AJAX Validation - error message formatting

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.3

I'm trying to create a form that is an ajax form that will have validation on 2 fields.

I have managed to get the form working via AJAX, but I'm having trouble returning the error messages [Link Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19492795/sonata-admin-custom-ajax-call/19493590)

I can determine that the form is valid using `$eventForm->isValid()` but I want to display errors for each of the invalid fields, preferably next to each form input/widget

Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render individually the label, input and errors of each field in the form:

```
{{ form_label(form.age) }}
{{ form_errors(form.age) }}
{{ form_widget(form.age) }}
```

More information in Symfony2 docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

**EDIT based on comments:**

Getting the html from an ajax request to a controller:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "{{path('yourpath')}}",
   cache: "false",
   dataType: "html",
   success: function(result){
        $("#somediv").append(result);    
   }
});
```

Comment: I have that, but how do I get them to be populated from the ajax response?

Comment: you can pass the rendered view as you want it to be displayed and then replace the content of a container with that: `success: function(data) { $('#somediv').html(data); }`

Comment: I managed to get things to work. I had to `serialize()` the form data as it was complaining about the `CSRF token`.